# Form validation error message show on submit in angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-forms

I am trying to validate form in angular 6 but not working. My code is in stackblitz.
How to validate that form and how to show error message?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-ctzf7f?file=app/app.component.html

```
     <div class="col-md-4">
             <label>
             <input type="radio" name="bhk" formControlName="onebhk" value="yes" /> 1 BHK
             </label>
             <label>
             <input type="radio" name="bhk" formControlName="onebhk" value="no" /> 2 BHK
            </label>
       </div>
```

TS:

```
  this.registerForm=new FormGroup({
  userType:new FormControl('',Validators.compose([
    Validators.required 
  ])),
  modalType:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
  place:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
  onebhk:new FormControl('',Validators.required),

  min:new FormControl('',Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.min(200) 

  ])),
  max:new FormControl('',Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.max(2000)

  ]))

})
```

Comment: Believe it would be of help if you posted the code in the question too.

Comment: @Ravindra:I think radio button validation is not working properly

Comment: Use this code on submit button to validate Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
        formGroup.get(key).markAsTouched();
        formGroup.get(key).updateValueAndValidity();
      });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to make submitted flag to true on submit and check error with following condition:
    `<p style="color:red" *ngIf="!registerForm.controls.userType.valid && 
    submitted">Required</p>`

here is your solution.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-cxzbr6?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can use create a formgroup and use formcontrol to validate the data.
Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-cy6avn

EXAMPLE

> component.ts

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
formSubmitted: boolean;
  testForm = this.fb.group({
    field1: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field2: ['', [Validators.required]],
  });

  isFieldValid(field: string) {
    return (
      this.testForm.get(field).errors && this.testForm.get(field).touched ||
      this.testForm.get(field).untouched &&
      this.formSubmitted && this.testForm.get(field).errors
    );
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.formSubmitted = true;
    if (this.testForm.valid) {
      alert('VALID');
    } else {
      alert('NOT VALID');
    }
  }
```

> component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="field1">
        <div *ngIf="isFieldValid('field1')">
            <div style="font-size: 12px; color: red">
                NOT VALID
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="field2">
        <div *ngIf="isFieldValid('field2')">
            <div style="font-size: 12px; color: red">
                NOT VALID
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div>
    <button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```